# Specifying CRS of raster layer using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I am manipulating NetCDF raster data from the QGIS Python Console. The metadata of my NetCDF file does not provide the Reference system. However, I know it is 'EPSG:4326'.

I am writing a Python script to perform tasks automatically, I don't want user interaction.

I am using the following commands :

```py
fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)`
```

But the QGIS windows asked me for the Coordinate reference system of this layer. I tried to specify the CRS while loading with something like:

```py
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(filename=fileName, basename=baseName, crs='EPSG:4326')
```

But QGIS crashes.

Is it possible to specify a QML file where the CRS is defined?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, the named parameter notation is causing the crash. Not sure if that should work. Anyway, you can set the CRS with [`setCrs()`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#afc72ec9bb0d3b98fe20b5b85c3d70512) method after you have made sure the CRS prompt is disabled:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour" )
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )

fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
rlayer.setCrs( QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId) )

s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, the qgis windows used to specify the crs appears with the command `rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)`. This is why I was looking for an way to pass it as an argument of the method.

Comment: right, then you need to disable the prompt first (and restore it afterwards).  See edited answer above.

Comment: QGIS 3 seems to have this setting spelt `defaultBehavior` (US spelling) and not `defaultBehaviour` (English spelling).

Answer (score 5):

I think another way to solve this problem is to set the CRS directly to the file stored on disk before creating layer reference in PyQGIS by using the [`QgsRasterLayer`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterLayer.html) constructor. It would avoid the QGIS window asking for the Coordinate Reference System. To test my suggestion I used a raster layer that was created without CRS (out_pyqgis.tif) and in the QGIS Python Console, I assigned the corresponding CRS to EPSG 4326 by using this code.

```py
from osgeo import osr, gdal
from gdalconst import *

dataset = gdal.Open('path_to_my_raster/out_pyqgis.tif', GA_Update)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
dataset.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )
dataset = None
```

It worked as expected. No more pop-up CRS window and the `QgsRasterLayer` constructor could be used in a condensed way:

```py
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to:
http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers
and http://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a65b118c0319a090c9efbf259bfebd55f
you provide too much informations.

The CRS used should be the one of the canvases (I suppose...).

And you can have it like this:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
actual_crs = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
```

If you want to change it:

```py
from qgis import core
from qgis.utils import iface

if iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().hasCrsTransformEnabled():    
    my_crs = core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
    iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(my_crs)
```